# i am getting errors im running on PHP

Tags: php

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['confirmpassword']);

$date = date ("Y-m-d");

i get **"Notice: Undefined index"**
but when i do this

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['confirmpassword']);

$date = date ("Y-m-d");
}
```

the undefined index gets fixed but **Notice: Undefined variable: submit** is my new error why is that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's notice because you want to use variable which is not set you can fix it by checking it with isset() function

```
$submit = null;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])
   $submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

or with short syntax

```
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null;
```

same applies to other variables passed via $_POST

Comment: this worked but why is that when i register i dont get any value? is it because of the null value??

Comment: null means it's still registered and has value null when variable is not declared then you get the notice.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn Presumably you don't have any element called 'submit' in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$submit = isset ( $_POST ['submit'] ) ? $_POST ['submit'] : null ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

In:

```
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to no value for 'submit' being passed by POST.
Check if $_POST['submit'] is empty prior to assigning its value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do You have in your form

```
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' />
```

if you have placed only

```
  <input type = 'submit' />
```

It will not work

Changed it to start with this

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) != "")
 {

   $submit = $_POST['submit'];
   ......

 }

 ?>
```